# Apply WPFTookit DataGrid Cell Style to only some DataGridColumn in WPF NET 3.5

Tags: wpf, datagrid, .net-3.5, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF Datagrid which has some columns and rows.

Now, I am trying to apply a style to only some DataGridColumn as below but it get the error:

> type reference cannot find a public type named 'DataGridCell'.

```
<my:DataGrid>

    <my:DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">          
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CellDateColorConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Date1"/>
                        <Binding Path="Date2"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </my:DataGrid.Resources>

    <my:DataGrid.Columns>   
        <my:DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCellStyle}">
           <my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle> 
           <!-- Stuff -->
           </my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle> 
        </my:DataGridTextColumn>
    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

I would like to apply to entire cell background not only to the textbox within cell.

For example below works but only changes background color for textbox within cell, but it does not work for changing entire cell background:

```
<my:DataGrid.Columns>   
    <my:DataGridTextColumn>
       <my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle> 
           <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
              <Setter Property="Background">
                 <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CellDateColorConverter}">
                       <Binding Path="Date1"/>
                       <Binding Path="Date2"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
           </Style>
       </my:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle> 
    </my:DataGridTextColumn>
</my:DataGrid.Columns>
```

The CellDateColorConverter static resource is a converter that compare the two dates and return a color or another depending on whether Date1 > Date2.

Comment: Did you forget to add the namespace, i.e. `TargetType="my:DataGridCell"`?

Comment: @Clemens You are right! prefix my: was missed. Now working. Please, post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I voted to close this question, because the problem was a simple typographical error, and an answer will unlikely be of any help for future readers. You may simply delete it.